# How to filter in Django and use a method of the class as the condition?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to get a queryset that only contains tutors who fulfill minimum requirements. The tutor class has a method "satisfies_min_requirements(self, student) -> bool". It basically figures out whether a tutor is fitting for the student.

I have an approach that works, but I think there must be a better way to do it. This is what I have:

```
tutors = Tutor.objects.all()

tutors = list(filter(lambda tutor : tutor.satisfies_min_requirements(student), tutors))
```

This is the function:

```
def satisfies_min_requirements(self, student: Student):    
    self_subjects = self.get_subjects()
    student_subjects = student.get_subjects()

    is_shared_subjects = False
    for stud_subj in student_subjects:
     if self_subjects.count(stud_subj) > 0:
       is_shared_subjects = True
       break

    if not is_shared_subjects: return False

    self_tut_places = self.get_tutoring_places()
    student_tut_places = student.get_tutoring_places()

    is_shared_places = False
    for student_place in student_tut_places:
      if self_tut_places.count(student_place) > 0:
        is_shared_places = True
        break

    if not is_shared_places: return False

    if self.get_distance(student.get_coordinates()) > 30: return False

    return True
```

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that, unless you find a way to express your `satisfies_min_requirements` method as SQL or a Django ORM expression.

If you're willing to share the definition of the `satisfies_min_requirements()` method, we may be able to help you with that.

Comment: I'll do that! Thank you!

Comment: @lionel you have a lot of nested function calls, such as `self.get_subjects()`, `student.get_subjects()`, `self.get_tutoring_places()`, `student.get_tutoring_places()`, `self.get_distance()`, `student.get_coordinates()`…

It will be harder to rewrite as a django orm query :s

Comment: you're welcome, I'll hope you'll find a way around that.